# Sorting an ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: wpf, sorting, observablecollection

I have a `UsersVM` (plural) and a `UserVM` (singular).  I create an `ObservableCollection<UserVM>` in `UsersVM`.  I have the `ObservableCollection<UserVM>` bound to a `Listview`.  When I edit a User in the list view, I want the `ObservableCollection` to re-order itself based on User Status.  Here is some code:

**UsersVM:**

```
public ObservableCollection<UserVM> UserList{ get; set; }

public UsersVM(IUserService userService)
{
    this._userService = userService;
    var users= userService.GetUsers();

    var userViewModels = users.Select(x => new UserVM
    {
        UserID= x.UserID,
        StatusID = x.StatusID,
        Status = x.Status,
    });

    this.UserList= new ObservableCollection<UserVM>(userViewModels);

    this.UpdateUserStatus= new RelayCommand<object[]>((s) => UpdateStatus(s));
}
```

**UserVM:**

```
public class UserVM: ViewModelBase
{
    public UserVM()
    {
    }

    public int UserID{ get; set; }
}
```

So if I change the status of an individual user I want the `UserList` to resort based on the user statuses.  I have read that the only way the `ObservableCollection` can re order is to implement some sorting algorithms, but even then you need to either Add, Remove, or Move something to get it to change?  I read that as:  If I want to see my re-ordered `ObservableCollection` then I need to Add, Remove, or Move.  I tried `UserList.Move(1,2);` and that didn't work.  I tried `UserList.Add(TestUserObject);` and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the pattern I use when I want to sort, group, filter an ObservableCollection. In this case you want to get the default view of the ObservableCollection and add a sort description to it.

```
protected ObservableCollection<UserVM> _users = new ObservableCollection<UserVM>();
protected ICollectionView _bindToMe;      

public UsersVM()
{
    _users.Add(new UserVM() {Status = "1"});
    _users.Add(new UserVM() {Status = "3"});
    _users.Add(new UserVM() {Status = "2"});
}

public ICollectionView BindToMe
{
    get
    {
        if (_bindToMe == null)
        {
            _bindToMe = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_users);
            _bindToMe.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Status", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        }
        return _bindToMe;
    }
}
```

Then you can update your ListView ItemsSource binding to

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding BindToMe}" />
```

to bind to the sorted view of your collection

**Alternatively** you can leave your ObservableCollection exposed on your ViewModel, bind to that and simply add the sort description to your ObservableCollection in the constructor of your ViewModel.

```
protected ObservableCollection<UserVM> _users;

public UsersVM()
{
    Users.Add(new UserVM() {Status = "1"});
    Users.Add(new UserVM() { Status = "3" });
    Users.Add(new UserVM() { Status = "2" });

    var view  = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_users);
    view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Status", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
}

public ObservableCollection<UserVM> Users
{
    get { return _users ?? (_users = new ObservableCollection<UserVM>()); }
}
```

Comment: It's also worth looking at "Live Shaping" as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you clarify your example a little bit more?  I am just confused at the naming convention you used. Where do I use BindToMe ?

Comment: Change your ListView ItemsSource binding to bind to BindToMe

Comment: Okay, but I don't see where _bindToMe gets instantiated.. what type is it and how does that part work??

Comment: You never actually bind directly to an ObservableCollection, you are always binding to an ICollectionView, all this code is doing is retrieving a reference to the view that, by default, you are binding to and adding a sortdescription to it.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for that?  Also, thank you so much!  I am having a kind of.. odd.. bug though.  I am breaking at the return _bingToMe statement and the list is sorted but it is NOT sorted properly in my view =/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57958/discussion-between-user1296981-and-stuart).

Comment: It's strange, it's not refreshing the ListView in my UI regardless.

Comment: You must have a binding error - the above works, I wrote the code in a new project and tested it before posting. Look in your debug output window for the text BindingExpression to find binding issues

Comment: Which piece?  THe ICollection code or the Observable?

Comment: Does the ListView need UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged?  Because I am not getting a Binding error.